# CSRF cookie not set Django если долго открыта страница

Tags: django

При обычном исползовании всё работает нормально, но после бездействия(открытой страницы в течениие 10 минут где-то) при попытке отправить форму через POST получаю `Forbidden(403) CSRF cookie not set`. Как это пофиксить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте settings.py на наличие

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

если есть - удалите. Также проверьте наличие django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware в MIDDLEWARE, оно должно быть ДО остальных middleware, которые используются вьюхами.
То же самое и для

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

также проверьте включены ли у вас куки в браузере

Comment: Стояло `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`, убрал, поверю отпишу. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Fyzzygood хорошо, если поможет не забудьте про галочку под ответом:)
надеюсь поможет вам